# Laravel behind a Firewall with private IP

Tags: laravel, firewall

Laravel shows me a private IP in the source code instead of the domain.
I used the route () command in the blade templates.

The APP is behind a Sophos XG Firewall.

How can I switch it to the domain ?

Comment: Change your APP_URL in your .env file

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when Laravel is not conscious about your web domain name. For example: if you are sending an email through `php artisan command` or anything that are not related to the web domain. To fix this issue you can set your current domain name in the `.env` file of Laravel project directory. In your `.env` file set `APP_URL=www.your-domain.com`. Then reference this variable to wherever you want: something like `env('APP_URL')`. This code will return `www.your-domain.com`. Now you can use this command to show your current domain name.

Comment: I have changed the .env file. Unfortunately without effect.